# Would anyone understand how the BSB (cf. eq 33) were deduced?

Tags: uncertain-volatility

I am trying to redemonstrate the dynamical programming equation and the compact formulation of the multiple-payoff problem given in the Appendix of the paper of Avellaneda on pricing and hedging derivative under the Uncertain Volatility Model (UVM).

http://math.cims.nyu.edu/faculty/avellane/UVMfirst.pdf.

Avellaneda, Levy, Paras: *Pricing and Hedging Derivative Securities in Markets with Uncertain Volatilities*, 1995

Does anyone understand how the BSB PDE (cf. eq 33) was deduced?